# Expand a Multi level Kendo Panelbar to one of its children

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I have a multi-level Kendo Panelbar;
I need to expand the panelbar all the way down to one of its child nodes;

this is the best I could come up with, but it's limited to the first level of the panel item:

```
var panelBar = $(pnlMonitorId).data("kendoPanelBar");
panelBar.select(panelBar.element.children("li").eq(0));

var item = panelBar.select();
panelBar.expand(item);
```

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, I consider the lack of support for the following a short coming:

```
panelbar.expand("...some deep node to expand to...")
```

anyways, I resolved the problem by:

```
var panelBar = $("#myPanel").data("kendoPanelBar");

//2 > 7 > 32
panelBar.select($('[id="2"]'));
var item = panelBar.select();
panelBar.expand(item);

panelBar.select($('[id="7"]'));
item = panelBar.select();
panelBar.expand(item);

panelBar.select($('[id="32"]'));
item = panelBar.select();
panelBar.expand(item);
```